# Выдает один и тот же результат при base64 енкодинге

Tags: http, golang, base64

У меня выдает один и тот же результат при `base64` енкодинге, хоть передаются совсем разные `ReadCloser (req.Body)`, такое чувство будто из слайса передается только последняя строка.

Код:

```
var urls []string {
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://go.com/goodbye",
}

for i, url := range urls {
    req, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        Enc(fmt.Sprintf("%v", req.Body))
    }
}

func Enc(msg string) {
    var encode = b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(msg))
    var decode, _ = b64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(encode)
    fmt.Println(string(encode), fmt.Sprintf("%v", decode))
}
```

Comment: нет. результаты разные. покажите, что у вас выводит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

возможно, проблкма в b64. Я не знаю с какого пакета берется b64, но с encoding/base64 результаты отличаются

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/base64"
)

var urls = []string{ "http://golang.org/", "http://go.com/goodbye" }

func main() {
    for _, url := range urls {
        req, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            Enc(fmt.Sprintf("%v", req.Body))
        }
    }
}

func Enc(msg string) {
    var encode = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(msg))
    var decode, _ = base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(encode)
    fmt.Println(string(encode), fmt.Sprintf("%v", decode))
}
```

> Jnt7MHhjNDIwMGNjMDAwfSA8bmlsPiA8bmlsPn0= [38 123 123 48 120 99 52 50
>   48 48 99 99 48 48 48 125 32 60 110 105 108 62 32 60 110 105 108 62
>   125]
>   JnsweGM0MjAxMjUyODAgezAgMH0gZmFsc2UgPG5pbD4gMHgxMWUxYTgwIDB4MTFlMWExMH0=
>   [38 123 48 120 99 52 50 48 49 50 53 50 56 48 32 123 48 32 48 125 32
>   102 97 108 115 101 32 60 110 105 108 62 32 48 120 49 49 101 49 97 56
>   48 32 48 120 49 49 101 49 97 49 48 125]

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам понял свою вину, у меня функция не обновлялась поэтому данные были одни и те же.

Answer (score 0):

```
fmt.Sprintf("%v", req.Body)
```

Вот тут вы печатаете *адрес* `req.Body`. Это интерфейсное значение. Его надо прочитать, например с помощью `io.ReadFull`:

```
b := make([]byte, 4*1024)
_, err := io.ReadFull(resp.Body, b)
// Check err.
Enc(string(b))
```